# How to read continuous stream of data from API using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Assume I have an API URL https://example that streams a HUMONGOUS amount of data continuously, and the stream itself is not a valid JSON

How do I @GET and read data from such an API using Retrofit2?

Comment: Use RxJava with Retrofit to achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Added in answer.

Comment: Using coroutine, Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672406/how-to-use-coroutine-in-kotlin-to-call-a-function-every-second

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example:

```
Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.flatMap(n -> apiCall())
.repeat()
.subscribe({

});
```